# Exception occurred while executing PS Script for saving list as a template.

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, powershell, list-template

Script:

```
$site = get-spweb("mysiteurl") 
$list = $site.Lists["List_Name"] 
$list.SaveAsTemplate(“Forms Template”,”Inc Template”,”Template for dump data”,0)
```

error:

Exception calling "SaveAsTemplate" with "4" argument(s): "The folder that would
 hold URL 'Lists/OOPS/Attachments/17776' does not exist on the server."

Comment: List attachments are stored in folders hidden in the list with the list items id. Find the list item that gives you an error an check if you see something weird with the attachment. And on the other hand, your quotes characters are messed up when copying from a bad code preview. Replace “ and ” with normal quotes. (")

Comment: I am just trying to save the list as a template without data, why it loops through the complete list?